# image is not loading in react native expo

Tags: react-native, expo

please consider this code

```
export default function App({navigation}) {
const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
const entry = ({navigation})
return (  
<View>
  <Image href={require('./assets/bg_login.jpg')}
  style = {[styles.image]}
    />
</View>
);
```

}

css:

```
image: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  },
```

I am trying to load the image with this code but for some reason it doesnt work and neither does it throw any error or any thing.

**what have I already tried**

1. I have already checked the image and it's fine
2. I have tried replacing the image and that doesnt work either
3. I have tried giving height and width in percentage
4. I have checked the path and image name everything is fine
   [image: screenshot of my code]

Answer (score 0):

you using **href** instead of **source**

```
      <Image source={require('./assets/snack-icon.png')} style={[styles.image]} />
```

updated, with full sample code that working
and you can remove the [] on style of image {styles.image}

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Image, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

export default function App({ navigation }) {
  const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');
  const entry = { navigation };

  return (
    <View>
      <Image source={require('./assets/snack-icon.png')} style={styles.image} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
  },
});
```

sample link https://snack.expo.dev/@rudiahmad/bossy-tortillas

maybe you have issue with the styling, are you sure put the correct style?

Comment: still does'nt work, I was trynna do it with href before. However I have used your code and it does'nt work either @bagi2info.com

Comment: thank you for the help. I tried your code and just like earlier it ran smoothly without throwing an error. However the output screen was still blank. I have encapsulated the code within an svg component and now it works fine and I can see the output. Really appereciate your help though. Thank you @bagi2info.com

Comment: aa, you're using Image from svg library, I didn't see it

Comment: yes, I just realized it too. React treates normal components and svg ones differently

Answer (score 0):

so for some reason the above code shows no output and doesnt throw an error either. I have figured out and alternative way to make it work and I will post it down here just in case someone encounters the same error again:

*Please ignore the additional dependencies i have imported, you probably wont be needing them, I have imported these because I plan to use them ahead in my code*

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions,TextInput, Pressable, 
BackHandler, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';
import Svg, { Image, Ellipse, ClipPath } from 'react-native-svg';
import  Animated, {useSharedValue, useAnimatedStyle, interpolate, 
withTiming, withDelay, color, Value}  from 'react-native-reanimated';


export default function App({navigation}) {
const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
const entry = ({navigation})
return (  
<View>
<Svg>
<Image href={require('./assets/background.jpg')}
width = {width} 
height = {height + 100}
preserveAspectRatio = "xMidYMid slice"
/>
</Svg>
</View>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should import Image from react-native package, instead of react-native-svg

Comment: yes, that was the problem. I have solved it now. Thank you for your response really appereciate it